# Loop function for a list of codes

Tags: functions, import, procedural-programming, excel, automation

I have a list of codes that start with importing column D of an excel sheet which has a hyperlink. Then, the code moves onto importing the text version of the hyperlink and further proceeds with textual analysis.

However, my code does this analysis once for one hyperlink and I have to manually change the row number to each time I run the code.

I would like for Mathematica to automate the import/textual analysis for all the hyperlinks in column D of the excel file. The textual analysis codes are more than 30 lines and I was not entirely sure if it would be possible to automate this process. Could anyone please help?

Below is the code for only the first few lines as I do not think the textual analysis code is relevant and too long to paste here (which will go inside the loop).  Thank you and I truly appreciate your help in advance!

Code below:

```
SetDirectory[]
dataset = Dataset[Import["proxy2020sampler.xlsx"]];
dataset1 = dataset[1, All, 4];
```

importing only column D which contains the hyperlinks
The excel file looks like below:

[image]

```
dataset2 = dataset1[21];
```

i have to manually update this number for each time the program runs the textual analysis

```
data = Import[dataset2, "Plaintext"];
```

Below is about 40 lines of textual analysis.

Comment: you have to give an example of your excel file.

Comment: I have updated to include a screenshot of the excel file used in the code!

Comment: Why not just do `data = Import[#, "Plaintext"]& /@ dataset[1, All, 4]`

Comment: Almost identical question posted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2070299).